# How to determine the better design?

Tags: design, architecture

What do I need to consider to determine which design I choose when I have the following scenario?

There are two cases to considerer;

- Given T a generic class, I have to do something with multiple T's (Iterating each one of them).
- In other cases, with the same T, I have to process just once.

In both cases, independent of what is T and how I'll need to process it, the class that comprises T will behave exactly the same way, therefore, I don't need to worry about implementation details.

There are 2 possible solutions, and I don't know what directions should I follow to decide between them.

- Always consider as a List, this is for sake of simplicity, since there are no difference  between a List of T and only T.
- Use inheritance; the first child class will receive a List of T and work with it, the second, a single T and work with it.

Are there some good pratices or some article to help to decide such cases?
I'm looking for something like this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scsyfw1d%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or your experience as well.

---

**UPDATE:**

The class I'm design is not T, but its composer.

Comment: Why can't you use a list of T everywhere? A single value of type T will be just a list of length 1.

Comment: Exactly, that's the question!

Comment: Do you have any control over these T objects? Or might they be anything?

Comment: But if you do not have any argument against my (rhetorical) question, you have your answer already.

Comment: @BillMichell They might be anything, they always implement the same interface that is the only thing its composer know.

Comment: @Giorgio The only argument I have is the sake of simplicity, I don't know the risks. I don't know the pros neither the cons of this design, that's the purpose of the question.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I'd suggest you reading about "composition over inheritance" and "loose coupling"

Comment: @KonradMorawski Thank's for the suggestion

Comment: @MatheusFreitas: Simplicity is a good argument. Don't introduce any extra complexity, unless you find a reason for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If processing every instance of `T` is independent of processing the others, I'd just create a class that processes one `T` and then enwrap it with a class that "feeds" it with a sequence of `T`s and just calls the first class in some sort of a `foreach` block.

I wouldn't use inheritance for that.

Simplified example (C#):

```
interface IFoo
{
    void DoStuff();
}

class FooProcessor<T> where T : IFoo
{
    public void Process(T item)
    {
        item.DoStuff();
    }
}

class MultipleFooProcessor<T> where T : IFoo
{
    // composition over inheritance - MultipleFooProcessor does not share any "genes" with FooProcessor, 
    // it just keeps an instance of it in a private field
    FooProcessor<T> processor;

    // we're passing a regular FooProcessor here. 
    // thanks to not using inheritance, we could eg. create an IFooProcessor interface
    // and pass a different implementation of IFooProcessor here, allowing for a more flexible design.
    // see: dependency injection, loose coupling
    public MultipleFooProcessor(FooProcessor<T> processor)
    {
        this.processor = processor;
    }

    public void Process(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    {
        foreach (T item in sequence)
        {
            Process(item);
        }
    }

    public void Process(T item)
    {
        processor.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If only the individual items T are being processed, without any relation to eachother, I would just create a single class that works on a single T. 
This keeps that class as simple as possible.
Iterating over multiple Ts and applying the action on each one can be the responsibility of some other class.
This way there is no reason to create a list object when working on an individual item, nor are there multiple classes which basically do the same thing.